# Set state in lifecycle method React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have React lifecycle method as follows:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.props.totalVehicles !== nextProps.totalVehicles){
        this.setState({animation: "cartCount"}, () => setTimeout(() =>  this.setState({animation: null}), 1000));
    }
}
```

But that gives me:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Header component.
```

How to set state in the lifecycle methods without getting those errors?

Comment: Ideally, you can set state in `componentWillReceiveProps`, the error could be because you are using `setTimeout`. It is setting state after the mounting is done, thus the error.

Comment: Are you somehow navigating away from the component before setTimeout is executed, you might try to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted/39767963#39767963 and setState in setTimeout only if the component is mounted

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Nope.

Comment: Your code seems correct otherwise, I tried to make a demo of it and its works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/ymmp7vxw61

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old questions, i'll answer it for future references.

When using `setState` (which is asynchronous) via `setTimeout`, you have to remember to clear the timeout on `componentWillUnmount`.
Otherwise, you might get to situations in which the `setState` is called after the element has already unmounted.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting it on `componentWillUpdate`? That way, you know that the component has mounted already. Docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

If you want to set up initial state, do it in `componentWillMount`.

More lifecycle methods in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Comment: What is componentWillUpdateProps, where did you read about it

Comment: BTW you should not touch `componentWillMount`, it's better to use `componentDidMount` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you component is mounted now. You can create trigger `mounted` in your state and manage it in lifecycles methods.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { mounted: false };
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({ mounted: true });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 this.setState({ mounted: false });
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 if(this.props.totalVehicles !== nextProps.totalVehicles && 
  this.state.mounted){
   this.setState({animation: "cartCount"}, () => setTimeout(() =>
    this.setState({animation: null}), 1000));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using state "mounted" try using instance variable "mounted":

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.mounted = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.mounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 this.mounted = false;
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 if(this.props.totalVehicles !== nextProps.totalVehicles && 
  this.mounted){
   this.setState({animation: "cartCount"}, () => setTimeout(() =>
    this.setState({animation: null}), 1000));
 }
}
```