# IsMounted() causing warning with react-native-navigation

Tags: reactjs, native

[image]

Has anyone seen this? What how can I get rid of it?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted/39767963#39767963

Answer (score 0):

@user1106888,

Please have a look at the issue's history before posting the duplicate issue here,

but still, based on this issue in Github (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3956),

We can solve this issue with the below:

> import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
>
> YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated']);