# isMounted() warning keeps showing in after upgrading to React Native 0.55.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, warnings, mobile-application

I am seeing isMounted() warning after I upgraded to latest React Native version 0.55.4.

[image]

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted/39767963#39767963

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the below code to your root index.js file.

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
```

Comment: you should rather explain why it is showing instead of muting those warnings

Comment: @HariharanL it is due to react native update that deprecated `isMounted` method, so you shouldn't worry about it so much.
wait for the library developer to update it then you can update your react native dependencies too..

Comment: @SirKoswara I am seeing this warning message too. I hoped to get an answer why it is so and how could I solve it, by clicking this question. but rather found a way to mute it. That's why I commented above. I know it is deprecated. It would be helpful to have a solution or workaround or update in function explanation here

Comment: @HariharanL here is a link(https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html), which has detailed explanation about the issue