# how to manage component mount and unmount to update state values?

Tags: react-native, cross-platform

I would like to know how to manage state property when the component mounts and `unmounts`.

I have a lot of different components in my application to maintain the application flow. I know about function `componentdidmount` and `componentWillUnmount`. and I also tried the solution about `_isMounted=true` on `componentdidmount` function and `check _isMounted` properties value when I update `setState` and then `update _isMounted=false` on `componentWillUnmount` function.
but this won't work when more two components come in the picture.

For example following links:

- https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component/
- [Is there a way to check if the react component is unmounted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted)

as per the example, I have made a common class which will update the value of a component in `setMounted` function and will return value in `getMounted` function to validate component is mounted or not. These methods work correctly on a single screen when I call another screen from a stack and update some values then comes back on the previous page and refresh page it will `ismount=false`.

```
class Mount {
    isMounted=false;
    getMounted=()=>{
        return isMounted;
    }
    setMounted=mounted=>{
        isMounted=mounted;
    }
}

var mount=new Mount();
export default mount;

class example extends component{
    componentDidMount=async()=>{
        mount.setMounted(true);
        await this.loadScreen();
        this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
            'willFocus',
            async() => {
            await this.loadScreen();
            }
        );
    }
    loadScreen=async()=>{
        //some other stuff
        if(mount.getMounted()){//second time value is false
            this.setState({value:'value'});
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        mount.setMounted(false);
    }
    //renderview where i call example2 on buttonclick

}
class example2 extends component{
    componentDidMount=async()=>{
        mount.setMounted(true);
        await this.loadScreen();
    }
    loadScreen=async()=>{
        //some other stuff
        if(mount.getMounted()){
            this.setState({value:'value'});
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        mount.setMounted(false);
        this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
    }
}
```

It was showing following warning before using mount functions:
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating only a single instance of your `Mount` class that is exported and shared across every instance of every component. You will need to create a new instance of Mount for each component instance:

```
class Mount {
   ...
}
// export the Mount class
export default Mount;

class example extends component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // create an instance of Mount for each component instance
      this.mount = new Mount();
    }
    componentDidMount=async()=>{
        this.mount.setMounted(true);
        await this.loadScreen();
        this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
            'willFocus',
            async() => {
            await this.loadScreen();
            }
        );
    }
    loadScreen=async()=>{
        //some other stuff
        if(this.mount.getMounted()){//second time value is false
            this.setState({value:'value'});
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.mount.setMounted(false);
    }
    //renderview where i call example2 on buttonclick

}
```

Notice the addition of the constructor and the use of `this.mount` instead of `mount` throughout.

Comment: your solution worked, I guess I have some other problem and it doesn't belong to the mount of a component. I have API call in load function which is async so maybe response comes in the unmounted second screen and thats why it is giving me mounted=false on willfocus subscription when load calls second time on first component.
sorry bit confusing