# How to know if React Component is mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

I am trying to show the error component (custom made component) in React JS when a error will occur after clicking a button. This component has a timeout of 2000 ms and after that it will fade away. But if I click the button multiple times the error component is coming multiple times and waiting for 2 seconds.

Now what I want is if I know that the error component is already mounted, then using a simple if-else condition I can handle the scenario.

So I want to know how to know if a particular component is mounted in React.

The error component has a default timeout that is 4 second. So when I click the button the Error component is appeared and waiting for 4 seconds to complete. Now in 4 seconds if I click again the button, then previously mounted error component is unmounted but still stays on the top of the screen. A new error component with same data appears on the top of the screen. So, for few ms we have 2 error components are visible in the screen. I want that if one is staying on the top of the screen no other component should be mounted.

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted

Comment: just use this._ismounted member paramter to know the component mount , he is correct

Answer (score 0):

send a callback as prop then call it from componentDidMount() send a flag from the callback write your logic in parent.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is clicked, set the `displayingError: true` in state.

On button click, check if the `displayingError` is `true`, if yes, do nothing, else display error.

After your delay, set `displayingError` back to `false`.

This way it's only showed once and no additional ones will be created while its up.

Comment: The error component has a default timeout that is 2 second. So when I click the button the Error component is appeared and waiting for 2 seconds to complete. Now in 2 seconds if I click again the button, then previously mounted error component is unmounted but still stays on the top of the screen. A new error component with same data appears on the top of the screen. So, for few ms we have 2 error components are visible in the screen. I want that if one is staying on the top of the screen no other component should be mounted.