# react + firebase unsubscribe is not a function in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to understand why the following code would trigger this error?

> TypeError
>   unsubscribe is not a function

It doesn't have such error when i used `.onSnapshot()` function instead of `get()`.

Thanks

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = database
      .collection("Maps")
      .doc(id)
      .collection("Entries")
      .get()
      .then(
        data => {
          data.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          });
          setLoading(false);
        },
        err => {
          setError(err);
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [id]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't unsubscribe from a `get()` call. Because of that, the `get()` doesn't return an unsubscribe method, and your call fails.

---

When you start listening for data with `onSnapshot`, the client keeps listening for changes to the data. For that reason it returns a function that you can call to stop listening.

When you call `get()` to load data, the client gets the data from the server once, and then immediately stops listening for changes. That's why there's no need to unsubscribe  (nor the possibility to stop) after you call `get()`.

---

If there's a chance that the loading of the data may take longer than the component is mounted, you'll want to check for the unmounting of the component inside the `then()` handler. For an example of this, see [Is there a way to check if the react component is unmounted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted)

Comment: thanks. whats the proper way of using get() in useEffect, and unsubscribe/clean it up when unmount? if i dont do `return () => unsubscribe();` console error shows cannot update state on a unmounted component, and might have memory leak

Comment: perfect. thanks! and `You can accept an answer in 6 minutes`. let me wait abit

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscribe() isn’t a function because what is returned from database is not a function. Call a function in return for cleanup. Have a function that does the clean up and call it.

Answer (score 0):

unsubscribe worked for real-time listener (onSnapshot). Get() is used in asynchronous function and return a promise.