# Reverse order of JavaScript code - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to count the number of times a button is pressed within a second.

It's working, for the most part, it tracks it and outputs it.

But the problem is that it outputs the button press count from the last second instead of the current second.

I think it would work if the order was reversed somehow, how do I fix up this function?  Thanks.

[image]

```
    const [clicksPerSecond, setClicksPerSecond] = useState(0);
    const [tempCounter, setTempCounter] = useState(0);
    const [tempCounter2, setTempCounter2] = useState(0);
    const { setCounter, counter } = useContext(CountContext);
```

```
    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(tempCounter);

        if (tempCounter != 0) {

            if (tempCounter == 1) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setClicksPerSecond(tempCounter2);
                    setClicksPerMinute(tempCounter2 * 60);
                    setTempCounter(1);
                    console.log('Clicks per second final: ' + tempCounter2);
                }, 1000)
    
            } else {
                setTempCounter2(tempCounter);
                console.log('Clicks per second: ' + tempCounter);
            }
        }

        setTempCounter(tempCounter + 1);
        
    }, [counter])
```

```
return (
        <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors.background }]}>
            <View elevation={7.5} style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background, borderRadius: 500 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}
                    style={[styles.counterButton, { backgroundColor: colors.primary, borderColor: colors.container, borderWidth: 0 }]}>
                    <Text></Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 60 }}>{counter}</Text>
                    <Text>{clicksPerSecond} CPS</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you explain more about the output

Comment: i dont know much else to explain to be honest, the output is displaying current count dynamically but when it gets to displaying the total count for the second, it displays it for the previous second, so its 1 second behind on counting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead just increment the count and decrement it after a second.

```
export default function App() {
  const [clicks, setClicks] = React.useState(0);

  const onClick = () => {
    setClicks((c) => c + 1);
    setTimeout(() => setClicks((c) => c - 1), 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
      <p>Clicked {clicks} times</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You will also need to track if the component is unmounted before decrement, which I think you can do using refs. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted)

Comment: but the problem isnt that its 1 number too high, its that its displaying the total count from 1 second earlier instead of now

Comment: It is displaying the instantaneous clicks per second. How is this 1 second earlier?

Comment: nevermind, my apologies
this function works however it sometimes sets the CPS back to 0 when i'm tapping 10+ times a second, not sure why

Comment: Strange. That shouldn't be happening. Let me see if I can repro it.