# Why isn't localStorage making state persist after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-localstorage-with-react-hooks-to-set-and-get-items/) tutorial to use localStorage in React:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  // In the original code, this is inside the `useVolume` hook
  const [volumes, setVolumes] = useState([0, 0, 0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const savedVolumes = localStorage.getItem('volumes');

    if (savedVolumes) {
      const parsedVolumes = JSON.parse(savedVolumes);
      setVolumes(parsedVolumes);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('volumes', JSON.stringify(volumes));
  }, [volumes]);

  // In the original code, this is inside the `useVolume` hook
  // with other functions that update `volumes`
  const updateVolumes = () => {
    const newVolumes = [0, 0, 1];
    setVolumes(newVolumes);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{JSON.stringify(volumes)}</div>
      <button onClick={updateVolumes}>Update Volumes</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I press the Update Volumes button, the `volumes` localStorage changes to `[0, 0, 1]`, but when I reload the page, volumes is back to `[0, 0, 0]` (localStorage is also back to `[0, 0 ,0]`).

How to change this code so that `volumes` and `localStorage` are `[0, 0, 1]` even after reloading the page?

[Live code at StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-react-ts-ir67zx?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Note: I placed `volumes`, `setVolumes`, and `updateVolumes` in `App()` to simplify the example. In the original app, they are in a [hook](https://gist.github.com/weiying-chen/ceac2266bb1f9f4b9bdeaa1c1fd3b715). That's why I decoupled localStorage from their logic. I thought keeping it separate from the hook would be a better separation of concerns.

Comment: I think you need a condition, before updating the local storage, to check whether volumes is not the initial value. I think the initial value is overwriting the saved value.

Comment: Have you tried this on a local development environment ? Looks like something to do with StackBlitz

Comment: @Dilshan Yes, the original code is in my local development environment. Same issue.

Comment: Take out the second `useEffect`, don't use effects as if there some sort of event handler.  The solution is just place your `localStorage.setItem` in your `updateVolumes` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the article you followed is really giving good advice here..

First mistake here, is that the `useEffect` is just not required.  There are generally 2 reasons to use `useEffect`.  Either something `async` needs to happen, and because React client side is `sync` a `useEffect` is handy, another reason might be to get access to a DOM element using a `ref`.  Neither of those criteria's apply to the problem your trying to solve here.

Another mistake is thinking that the `useEffect` is to act like some sort of state change event, eg. If some state changes, run this code.  No that's not what it's meant for.  I know it looks like that, so an easy mistake to make.  Having an effect update state based on some state updating is really asking for trouble.

So after taking all that into account your code can be as simple as ->

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [volumes, setVolumes] = useState(
    () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('volumes') ?? '[0,0,0]'));

  const updateVolumes = () => {
    const newVolumes = [0, 0, 1];
    localStorage.setItem('volumes', JSON.stringify(newVolumes));
    setVolumes(newVolumes);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{JSON.stringify(volumes)}</div>
      <button onClick={updateVolumes}>Update Volumes</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Notice in the above I've also used the callback version of `useState`, the reason for that is that we only need to load from localeStorage on mount, it will work without it, but there is no point in loading from localeStorage for it just be ignored as state on subsequent renders doesn't use the initial value anyway.

Comment: That's simpler, less troublesome. Thanks. One question: With this method, now there's `localStorage` in my [useVolume hook](https://gist.github.com/weiying-chen/78bca9d06b0c770a05cfca8522c0f237). Do you think this is against the principle of separation of concerns (handling the volumes state vs. handling localStorage)?

Comment: @wyc  personally, having `useVolumeHook` handle it's state & it's backed state (localeStorage) seems totally logical to keep together here.  It could be split up, and the good thing is this can be done later if you spot a lot of repeated code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you use StrictMode

On strict mode react run your components twice which cause to reset volume in localstorge.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Remove the strict mode and it will start to work as expected. However when you design your components make sure no matter how many times it get called the result is same.

I would recommend you to read the documentation instead of those old tutorials. https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

---

UPDATED

You don't need that 2nd useEffect. We exactly know when the volumes is about to update. So just save it in the eventhandler

```
  const updateVolumes = () => {
    const newVolumes = [0, 0, 1];
    setVolumes(newVolumes);
    localStorage.setItem('volumes', JSON.stringify(newVolumes));
  };
```

Notice I used `newVolumes` not the `volumes` because `setVolumes` does not update the state but just schedule an update to do later. So the `volumes` is still holding the old state.

Check this for more info - https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Comment: How can I modify the code so that I get the desired result even in strict mode?

Comment: I thought about that solution, but that means that in the [original code](https://gist.github.com/weiying-chen/ceac2266bb1f9f4b9bdeaa1c1fd3b715), I have to do `localStorage.setItem` in each function that modifies `volumes`. Is that still better than using `useEffect`?

Comment: Then don't run the 2nd useEffect on mount. you can use `useRef` to check if the component is mounted or not and only run the 2nd useEffect if it is mounted. But i would strongly recommend you to not to do so and set the localStorage in the event handlers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719707

Comment: @wyc `in each function that modifies volumes`  Yeah, it looks like your not understanding what `effects` are meant for, that dependency is not there to act like some sort of change event for state.  In fact your code you posted requires zero `useEffect` calls..  There is not `effect` here..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Last question: How is the component running twice resetting localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

let's walk through your code and you'll see why thats happening. you are setting the state by default to [0, 0, 0] on mount both useEffect will run essentially overwriting whatever was in localstorage what you can do is something like this

```
const savedVolumes = localStorage.getItem("volumes");
  const [volumes, setVolumes] = useState(JSON.parse(savedVolumes) ?? [0, 0, 0]);
```

where you only set default value conditionally if local storage is empty

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work. But that part of the code is in a `useVolume` hook.  So I should pass `savedVolumes` as an argument? https://gist.github.com/weiying-chen/ceac2266bb1f9f4b9bdeaa1c1fd3b715

Comment: You can do that. or just move the entire useEffect into the hook